# How can I run an exe from stdout?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, curl, stdout, exec

I have a .exe file hosted as a release on a Github project, it is my project so I know this file is secure as I have compiled it. https://github.com/USERNAME/PROJECT/releases/latest/download/TORUN.exe is the link which gives me this file. I want to do something like this:

```
curl -o- https://github.com/USERNAME/PROJECT/releases/latest/download/TORUN.exe | bash
```

What is the `bash` replacement on Windows, or something I can call to run a .exe file?

Comment: Download the file and run `TORUN.exe`? It's a binary, not a script - no need for a script interpreter.

Comment: I know I can save this file to %TEMP%, but I am hoping to put this in my Github README, so other people can run it, so it might conflict with what they have in THEIR %TEMP%. Do you think this is a problem?

Comment: @Panki I know, but how would I run a .exe printed to stdout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *should* work.

```
curl -o %TEMP%\TORUN.exe https://github.com/USERNAME/PROJECT/releases/latest/download/TORUN.exe && .\%TEMP%\TORUN.exe
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

In short, you don't.

Bash, even on Linux, cannot actually run "exe" files from stdout in the first place. All the `curl|bash` commands you've seen are ones that run *Bash scripts* only – a compiled executable cannot be run that way. (Keep in mind Bash only asks the OS to run an executable, it's not Bash but the OS that loads and executes it...) If a compiled executable is involved, such a script usually downloads it to /tmp and runs it from there.

The same applies to Windows; it generally cannot run an .exe that isn't stored in an actual file. It is somewhat common to see the PowerShell equivalent of curl|bash, typically using its built-in `iwr` (Invoke-WebRequest) command to download the script instead of curl, but direct in-memory execution is still limited to PowerShell scripts and not .exe files.

(There are complex ways to load an executable in memory, but they'll likely bring attention from your anti-malware systems.)

Comment: Thank you, I will do something else.

Comment: I know. I've seen the `iwr | iex` a lot of times, I was just wondering if you could do something similar with executables.